# Frequency differences from MP3 to mic

Tags: audio, microphone

I'm trying to compare sound clips based on microphone recording. Simply put I play an MP3 file while recording from the speakers, then attempt to match the two files. I have the algorithms in place that works, but I'm seeing a slight difference I'd like to sort out to get better accuracy.

The microphone seem to favor some frequencies (add amplitude), and be slightly off on others (peaks are wider on the mic).

I'm wondering what the cause of this difference is, and how to compensate for it.

Background:
Because of speed issues in how I'm doing comparison I select certain frequencies with certain characteristics. The problem is that a high percentage of these (depending on how many I choose) don't match between MP3 and mic.

Answer (score 1):

It's called the response characteristic of the microphone. Unfortunately, you can't easily get around it without buying a different, presumably more expensive, microphone.

Comment: Its not possible to for example distort the MP3 file to achieve similarity? Blur? Sharpen? Hann/Hamming window? Reduce resolution by a small factor after FFT?

Comment: @Kilian Foth: why, it's possible to compensate if we don't mind phase distortions. In the case Tedd describes phase inconsistency is inevitable per se.

Comment: It's certainly *possible* to create a distorting filter that counteracts the characteristic distortion of a particular microphone. (If nothing else, machine learning could be used...) I just don't see that being remotely simpler than using a better mic. Cheaper, maybe. I guess this has verged into hardware.stackoverflow.com?

Comment: What microphone is being used is not really my choice. I can predict a few if absolutely required, and work with less quality on the rest.

Answer (score 0):

If you can measure the actual microphone frequency response by some method (which generally requires having some etalon acoustic system and an [anechoic chamber](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anechoic_chamber)), you can compensate for it by applying an equaliser tuned to exactly inverse characteristic, like discussed [here](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/315830-Frequency-response-correction). But in practice, as Kilian says, it's much simpler to get a more precise microphone. I'd recommend a [condenser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condenser_microphone#Condenser_microphone) or an electrostatic one.

Comment: The microphone is not really known in advance. I can limit it to a selection of microphones though. Would I play whitenoise for a second, then calculate average on each frequency and apply the reverse to the input? That may handle the favoring of frequencies, but not the "wide peaks" - right?

Comment: Yes, that's a reasonable approach (though I'd increase the duration to a dozen of seconds). The possible drawback of this method is that you will actually measure the resultant of both mic and speaker responses, though it can actually become an advantage in your case.